# Identity with inverse matrix multiplication $(A_1+A_2)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we have that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are matrices, how can I prove that $$I-A_1(A_1+A_2)^{-1} = A_2(A_1+A_2)^{-1}$$ if $(A_1+A_2)^{-1}$ exists? The case where we have numbers makes intuitive sense but here I am having trouble explicitly coming up with a reason why. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you just multiply both sides by $(A_1+A_2)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}I-A_1(A_1+A_2)^{-1}&=(A_1+A_2)(A_1+A_2)^{-1}-A_1(A_1+A_2)^{-1}\\[0.2cm]&=(A_1+A_2-A_1)(A_1+A_2)^{-1}\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$I-A_1(A_1+A_2)^{-1} = A_2(A_1+A_2)^{-1}$$

$$ \iff I(A_1+A_2)-A_1(A_1+A_2)^{-1}(A_1+A_2) = A_2(A_1+A_2)^{-1}(A_1+A_2)$$

$$ \iff (A_1+A_2)-A_1 = A_2$$

$$ \iff (A_1+A_2) = A_2 + A_1$$